Chart.js line plot with multiple overlapping datasets
I'm trying to draw several lines on the same graph.
The different datasets have different labels (the X axis comes from a TIMESTAMP sql).
Here, the different datasets are concatenated, but they should overlap. The times on the x axis are not correctly placed: they are not in ascending order. For example, "test compe FR A" should be first and the other two should cross.
<canvas id="evolution"></canvas>


<script>
    new Chart(document.getElementById("evolution"), {
        type : 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [
            
            {
                data:
                    [{x:'2024-07-11 21:34:52',y:2.0 },{x:'2024-07-11 21:56:03',y:2.5 },{x:'2024-07-11 21:56:08',y:2.590909090909091 },{x:'2024-07-11 21:56:10',y:2.6526408742472913 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:23:17',y:2.699817891112814 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:23:19',y:2.7381352863116124 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:23:36',y:2.7704545546847075 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:23:38',y:2.798429443881428 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:29:59',y:2.9158474606624587 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:32:58',y:2.930367008527791 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:33:22',y:1.9439602188279055 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:33:23',y:1.508122685970799 },],
                label:"test math A"
            },
            
            {
                data:
                    [{x:'2024-07-11 22:23:31',y:2.0 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:25:22',y:2.5 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:25:23',y:2.590909090909091 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:30:00',y:2.6526408742472913 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:30:01',y:2.699817891112814 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:30:02',y:2.7381352863116124 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:31:14',y:2.7704545546847075 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:31:15',y:2.798429443881428 },{x:'2024-07-11 22:31:19',y:2.823106289650891 }],
                label:"test math B"
            },
            
            {
                data:
                    [{x:'2024-07-11 09:03:38',y:2.0 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:29:13',y:2.5 },{x:'2024-07-12 12:33:40',y:2.590909090909091 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:33:55',y:2.6526408742472913 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:34:20',y:2.699817891112814 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:34:31',y:2.7381352863116124 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:34:38',y:2.7704545546847075 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:34:53',y:2.798429443881428 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:36:44',y:2.823106289650891 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:37:50',y:2.845190848296859 },{x:'2024-07-11 12:37:55',y:1.8651824730156372 },],
                label:"test compe FR A"
            },
            
            ]
        },
        options : {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time'
                }]
            },
            title : {
                display : true,
                text : 'Evolution'
            }
        }
    });
</script>



First of all you should specify the version of chart.js you are using; I assume, by the look of your scale options that you are using an old 2.x version of the library (otherwise, you'd get an explicit warning in console).

If you link to a v2 bundle, see fiddle, the time values are parsed correctly, and placed in the correct and proportional order on the x axis - which is rather difficult to read since the gap between the datasets is much larger than the span of each dataset. However, the values in a dataset are not sorted (you may sort them yourself), and you have a data point in the third dataset that is in the wrong day, which gives the chart an unusual look (I excluded that in the fiddle).
